# How to allow CSS content to be rendered in my local Apache web server with chrome?

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I imported my CSS file(public/css/style.css) into my about view(views/about.view.php) via my head partial head.php:

```
7 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/style.css">
```

However I receive the warning **"Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html"**

I've used this forum for guidance: https://serverfault.com/questions/405229/apache-delivering-css-and-js-files-but-browsers-dont-render-them

The actions I've taken are based on the existing forum post above which unfortunately has not proven successful. Before those changes though, i'd like to say my current relevant environment.

I'm using XAMPP to start an Apache web server. My project specific files are located at "/php/php-practitioner/" and i've rewritten my base with a .htaccess file which was successful proven to work by visting in my browser "localhost/about" which loads my HTML & PHP content A-Okay.

By following this answer I added the following code to my .htaccess file:

```
3 AddType text/css .css
4 AddType text/javascript .js
```

Full .htaccess file

```
 1 RewriteEngine On
 2 RewriteBase /php/php-practitioner/
 3 AddType text/css .css
 4 AddType text/javascript .js
 5 RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [END]
```

The answer also states that i need to confirm mod_mime is turned on in my .httpd.conf file. I have confirmed this by seeing that "LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so" already had no # symbol next to it.

Restarted my server and loaded the webpage again. However the warning is still there.

This solution has not worked and the same warning still appears.

My understanding is that editing a .htaccess file is project specific and editing the .httpd.conf file affects every project I create with XAMPP.

What i'm expecting from the stackoverflow community is someone to either point out a flaw in my implementation of the forum post solution or suggest an alternate solution. I appreciate the assistance :)

Edit: The Warning Appears in my Chrome browser when I check the console

Directory:

```
C:xampp\htdocs
        |_dashboard
          |_...
        |_img
          |_...
        |_php
          |_php-practitioner (This is my project)
            |_controllers
              |_about.php
              |_about-culture.php
              |_contact.php
              |_index.php
            |_core
              |_...
            |_public
              |_css
                |_style.css
            |_views
              |_partials
                |_footer.php
                |_head.php
                |_nav.php
              |_about.view.php
              |_about-culture.view.php
              |_contact.view.php
              |_index.view.php
        |_webalizer
        |_xampp
          |_...
        |_.htaccess
        |_applications.html
        |_bitnami.css
        |_favicon.ico
```

Comment: `.htaccess` applies to the directory it's in. `httpd.conf` does not necessarily apply to all projects. it depends on where you put the rewrite rules.

Comment: where are you getting the warning?

Comment: The warning appears in my chrome browser

Comment: If you are using XAMPP, your files should be in a folder within the `htdocs` folder

Comment: Yep so i know that the htdocs folder is the root of my project, however for this specific project i have rewrote the base of my project  with this "RewriteBase /php/php-practitioner/" so i'm just looking at my project files instead of all of xampps files. When i load localhost, it gets redirected to /php/php-practitioner which is where my index.php is. Would you like me to post the working directory from htdocs onwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR; I had my code in a sub directory that was unable to find my stylesheet

Hi Windows Users on Xampp/mampp/lampp in 2019. I have a fix that worked for me that will work for you and it's to do with our environment setup. This was from a Laracasts Tutorial. [PHP Practitioner](https://laracasts.com/series/php-for-beginners/episodes/17)

This was a breaking point for me and i made it over so you can too!

This is regarding both the errors where you copied jeffs code and still get a 404 OR
you receive the error "Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html".

First off, your .htaccess file should look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
AddType text/css .css
AddType text/javascript .js
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [END]
```

Secondly all of your project files MUST 1000% go to your htdocs folder located at: C:\xampp\htdocs

Finally, if you are getting any more errors after this please email me at roman.ozerski@icloud.com and i will personally help you